# KeyboardAwareScrollView on the button

Tags: react-native

I have one button at the bottom of the screen and input field on the top of the screen. When `<TextInput>` is focused - keyboard overlaps a button and it cannot be pressed until I click the return button. I want the Submit button to be pushed up when the keyboard is opened and return back to the bottom of the screen when the keyboard is not active.

KeyboardAwareScrollView works well with `<TextInput/>` however seems like doesn't work with the button. Any ideas how can I achieve that? Thanks!

```
render() {
    return (
        <KeyboardAwareScrollView
            contentContainerStyle={{
                flex: 1,
                flexDirection: 'column',
                justifyContent: 'flex-end',
                alignItems: 'center',
                backgroundColor: 'skyblue'
            }}
        >

            <View>
                <TextInput placeholder='John'
                           autoFocus={true}/>
                <Button>
                    <Text>Submit</Text>
                </Button>
            </View>
        </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

KeyboardAwareScrollView has a prop called `extraScrollHeight` which can be used for this purpose.

https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view#props

> **extraScrollHeight** - Adds an extra offset to the keyboard. Useful if you want to stick
>   elements above the keyboard.

You could couple this with the `onFocus` prop to set the `extraScrollHeight` so that the keyboard remains below the button.

```
<KeyboardAwareScrollView
  contentContainerStyle={{
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection: 'column',
      justifyContent: 'flex-end',
      alignItems: 'center',
      backgroundColor: 'skyblue'
  }}
  extraScrollHeight={this.state.extraScrollHeight}>
  <View>
    <TextInput 
      ref={ref => { this.textInput = ref; }}
      placeholder='John'
      onFocus={(event) => {
        this.setState({extraScrollHeight:30})
      }}
      autoFocus={true}
      />
    <Button> 
      <Text>Submit</Text>
    </Button>
  </View>
</KeyboardAwareScrollView>
```

This would allow you to dynamically set the `extraScrollHeight` depending on the `TextInput` you were looking at. You would need to manage the `extraScrollHeight` on every `TextInput`.

Alternatively you could just set an `extraScrollheight` and leave it.

---

## Update for moving button above keyboard

The question poster updated their question to state that the TextInput was at the top of the page, while the button is at the bottom. The button show move up above the keyboard.

Alternatively you could add listeners to the `Keyboard`, as that will get the height of the keyboard and allow you to animated the Button up.

1. `import { Keyboard, Animated } from 'react-native'`
2. Set a new `Animated.Value` in the state for the initialPosition of the Button.
3. Add listeners to `keyboardDidShow` and `keyboardDidHide` in the `componentDidMount` and remove them in the `componentWillUnmount`
4. Add the methods to for `_keyboardShow` and `_keyboardHide` which will animate the Button up above the height of the keyboard
5. Contain the Button in an `Animated.View` with the position set by `this.state.initialPosition`

Here is the code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Animated, Button, TextInput, Keyboard } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      initialPosition: new Animated.Value(60)
    }
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.keyboardShowListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', this._keyboardShow);
    this.keyboardHideListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', this._keyboardHide);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.keyboardShowListener.remove();
    this.keyboardHideListener.remove();
  }

  _keyboardHide = (e) => {
    Animated.timing(
      this.state.initialPosition,
      {
        toValue: 60
      }
    ).start();
  }

  _keyboardShow = (e) => {
    Animated.timing(
      this.state.initialPosition,
      {
        toValue: e.endCoordinates.height
      }
    ).start();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
          <TextInput 
            placeholder='Enter first name'
            autoFocus
            style={{fontSize: 24}}
          />
          </View>

        <Animated.View style={{bottom: this.state.initialPosition}}>
          <Button 
            onPress={() => alert('submit')} title={'submit'} 
          />
        </Animated.View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
  },
  mainContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center'
  }
});
```

Here is a snack https://snack.expo.io/@andypandy/animated-button-above-keyboard

It is worth noting

> Note that if you set android:windowSoftInputMode to adjustResize or
>   adjustNothing, only keyboardDidShow and keyboardDidHide events will be
>   available on Android. keyboardWillShow as well as keyboardWillHide are
>   generally not available on Android since there is no native
>   corresponding event

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboard#addlistener

Otherwise I would use `keyboardWillShow` and `keyboardWillHide` as they will be called before the keyboard is shown/hidden making the animation a little slicker.

## Final thoughts

Obviously this is a proof of concept but it should give you a good idea on how to accomplish what you want.

One thing that you could do to make it more performant is if you display the keyboard anywhere before in the application is to capture the height of the keyboard and save it so that you can access later. You could save it in `redux`, `AsyncStorage`, or just pass it through your navigation to this screen. Then you could use the `onFocus` property of the `TextInput` to move the Button.

Comment: thanks for your response. Problem is that my <TextInput> is on the top of the screen and in general never affected by keyboard but the button is at the bottom, therefore, this approach has no effect in mine scenario. Any ideas on how to adopt this approach to my case?

Comment: You could use an animation on the button so that it translates up the screen so that it is above the keyboard. The animation could be triggered by the onFocus event

Comment: Probably this will be quite complicated to achieve since I need to detect a keyboard height in order to know for how many pixels I need to push it above?

Comment: I had some thought on how you could do it and have updated my answer to  show to move a button above the keyboard.

Comment: Andrew, thank you very much, this is a great answer!

Comment: @Andrew In your first command the this.state.extraScrollHeight valus is applying for all the inputbox in a same way. Here I have more than 3 inputbox. Need to showextraScrollHeight  = 200 whileclick on only one of the inputbox. How can I achieve this? Any solution for this?

Comment: I have a clarification. Is this is a good practice to do setState in all inputBox. Does this not make any performance issue. (i.e) It will re-render the screen for every input which types in input box

Answer (score -3):

Not sure if this is still relevant, but this worked for me. Hope this might help others in the future. The trick is to put Keyboard Aware Scrollview inside of a View. You have an additional View that is attached to the flex-end. This will always stay to the bottom of your screen.

```js
<View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection:'column'}}>
  <KeyboardAwareScrollView>
    {...things that need to scroll}
  </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
  <View style={{flex-direction:'flex-end'}}>
    {...whatever button or text}
  </View>
</View>
```