# How to handle the inputBox is focus with keyboardAwareScrollView of scrollheight

Tags: react-native, keyboard, textinput

I have a input box with dropdown. Here I have used KeyboardAwareScrollView. I have set extraScrollHeight for the entire screen.

How to set the extraScrollHeight is 100 if I focuused on a particular inputBox on my screen.

Refer the code which I have tried

```
state = { isFocused: false }

   handleInputFocus = () => this.setState({ isFocused: true })

  <KeyboardAwareScrollView bounces = {false}
            style = {{marginBottom:"7%"}}
            scrollEnabled={true}
            onFocus={this.handleInputFocus}
            keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'always'} stickyHeaderIndices = {[0]}
            extraScrollHeight = { isFocused ? 0 : 100 }
            >

  <TextInput underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'} style={{borderWidth: 1,
          borderColor: '#d6d7da',
          backgroundColor: '#ffffff'}} value={name} />
```

Comment: Check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54381446/keyboardawarescrollview-on-the-button). This can help you.